# problem with rosws merge

Tags: ros, rosws, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run "roslocate info ROSARIA | rosws merge -" in order to install ROSARIA, happens an error:

```
basilio@lcarobo:~/fuerte_workspace$ roslocate info ROSARIA | rosws merge -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosws", line 64, in <module>
    sys.exit(rosinstall.rosws_cli.rosws_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 440, in rosws_main
   return ws_commands[command](workspace, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 277, in cmd_merge
    pipedata = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

how can I fix it? is there any package missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49830/problem-with-rosws-merge/) by [alessandrayoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/3730/alessandrayoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug in rosws: https://github.com/vcstools/rosinstall/issues/27
a patch has been released today with rosinstall 0.6.22. update, and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3